# Adapting odoo report for email - How to change env for current partner_id only

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I have a odoo report from the OCA that I am trying to adapt to be able to be sent as an email to individual customers. The report is seen here [Report and Github link](https://github.com/OCA/account-financial-reporting/blob/10.0/customer_activity_statement/report/customer_activity_statement.py)

The below is the important part (as I see it). In this function 'data' is passed through from a wizard.

```
 @api.multi
def render_html(self, docids, data):
    company_id = data['company_id']
    partner_ids = data['partner_ids']
    date_start = data['date_start']
    date_end = data['date_end']
    today = fields.Date.today()

    balance_start_to_display, buckets_to_display = {}, {}
    lines_to_display, amount_due = {}, {}
    currency_to_display = {}
    today_display, date_start_display, date_end_display = {}, {}, {}

    balance_start = self._get_account_initial_balance(
        company_id, partner_ids, date_start)
```

When I attempt to add the report to an email template as an attachement, I do not know how to pass through parameters to it as well. So I did the following:

If Data is None...

```
data={

    'date_start': str(date.today()-timedelta(days=120)),

    'date_end': str(date.today()),

    'company_id': self.env.user.company_id.id,

    'partner_ids': self._context['active_ids'],

    'show_aging_buckets': True,

    'filter_non_due_partners': True,

}`
```

**The problem is '        'partner_ids': self._context['active_ids'], '
Returns every customers statement on the email to every customer. How do I make it so this is only for the current customer?**

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: `self._context['active_ids']` returns a record set? If not what data type is it?